# Allow user to vote only once for a comment [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a table `vote` and `comment` I would to allow a user to vote only once for a `comment_id`. For now a user can vote multiple times for a comment.

I would like before to persist user in the table vote to verified if the current user_id has already voted for a specify `comment_id`, if yes the vote will not be persist.

**Controller.php**

```
public function voteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $comment = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Comment')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
    $entity = new Vote();
    $entity->setUser($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
    $entity->setVotecomment($comment);
    $entity->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('userShow', array(
    'entity' => $entity->getVotecomment()->getRecipient(),
    'slug' =>  $entity->getVotecomment()->getRecipient()->getId(),
        )));
}
```

.

**vote.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /**
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="vote")
     *
     */

    class Vote
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;


        /**
         * @var User
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="likes")
         */
        protected $user;

        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Comment", inversedBy="votes", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="votecomment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *
         */
        private $votecomment;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime", nullable=false)
         */
        protected $createdAt;


        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $this->votecomment = new ArrayCollection();
        }

}
```

.

**twig file**

```
<a class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" href="{{ path('likecomment', {'entity': entity ,'slug': entity.recipient.id ,'id': entity.id}) }}"></a><b class="text-color">&nbsp; &nbsp;{{ entity.votes|length }}</b>
```

Comment: In your voteAction, check that the vote already doesn't exist first (with a find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I needed just to check if the current user has already voted for a comment.

Below an example of how I did it :

```
   public function voteAction(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();


        $comment = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Comment')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
        $voteExist = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Vote')->findOneBy([
            'user' => $this->getUser(),
            'votecomment' => $comment
        ]);
        $vote = new Vote();
        if(!$voteExist) {

            $vote->setUser($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
            $vote->setVotecomment($comment);
            $vote->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $em->persist($vote);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('userShow', array(
                'entity' => $vote->getVotecomment()->getRecipient(),
                'slug' => $vote->getVotecomment()->getRecipient()->getId(),
            )));



        } else {

            $em->remove($voteExist);
            $em->flush();
            //$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'You have already voted!');

        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('userShow', array(
            'entity' => $comment->getRecipient(),
            'slug' => $comment->getRecipient()->getId(),
        )));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [Symfony Validation component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) and add [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) validation constraint to your Vote entity. Using this way you can validate your entity uniqueness by two fields ($user and $votecomment).

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this solution**
Of course, you can create *$hasVote* by creating custom method on **Comment** repository.

```
public function voteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $hasVote = $em
        ->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Comment')
        ->find(array(
            'id' => $id,
            'user' => $this->getUser())
        );

    if ($hasVote){

        // Add flash - already voted
        // Redirect to route...
    } else {

        $comment = $em
        ->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:Comment')
        ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

        $vote = new Vote();
        $vote->setUser($this->getUser());
        $vote->setVotecomment($comment);
        $vote->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

        $em->persist($vote);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('userShow', array('entity' => $entity->getVotecomment()->getRecipient(),'slug' =>  $entity->getVotecomment()->getRecipient()->getId(),)));
    }
}
```